# Hot to open Table View upwards after pressing a button?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

Is there a way to open my table view upwards instead of downwards after pressing the button in swift?

When I press the button and open TableViewControler, there is not enough space below to show all the possible options in the table view, hence, I am wondering if there is any way to open tableview upwards?

Attaching a screenshot of the problem below:[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P665P.jpg)

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light

        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(CellClass.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }
    
    
    //MARK: What happens when you click "When"
    
    func addTransparentView(frames: CGRect) {
        let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
        transparentView.frame = window?.frame ?? self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(transparentView)
        
        tableView.frame = CGRect(x: frames.origin.x, y: frames.origin.y + frames.height, width: frames.width, height: 0)
        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        
        
        transparentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.9)
        tableView.reloadData()
        let tapgesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(removeTransparentView))
        transparentView.addGestureRecognizer(tapgesture)
        transparentView.alpha = 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.transparentView.alpha = 0.5
            self.tableView.frame = CGRect(x: frames.origin.x, y: frames.origin.y + frames.height + 5, width: frames.width, height: CGFloat(self.dataSource.count * 50))
        }, completion: nil)
    }
    
    @objc func removeTransparentView() {
        let frames = selectedButton.frame
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.transparentView.alpha = 0
            self.tableView.frame = CGRect(x: frames.origin.x, y: frames.origin.y + frames.height, width: frames.width, height: 0)
        }, completion: nil)
    }   


         @IBAction func selectTimeButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        dataSource = ["NOW ", "THIS EVENING ", "ANYTIME TODAY ", "IN A FEW HOURS ⏳", "SOMETIME TOMORROW ✨", "TOMORROW EVENING ", "OVER THE WEEKEND "]
        selectedButton = selectTimeButton
        addTransparentView(frames: selectTimeButton.frame)
        timeDetails = selectedButton.titleLabel?.text ?? "nothing is here in timedetails"
        print(timeDetails, "from selectTImeBUttonPressed")

    }


    extension WhatDoYouWannaDoViewController   {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = dataSource[indexPath.row]
        cell.backgroundColor = .white
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "ContrailOne-Regular", size: 20)!

        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedButton.setTitle(dataSource[indexPath.row], for: .normal)
        removeTransparentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes there is a way, but you should always show some piece of code, that you have tried. Otherwise no-one can help. So in your case, we even can't recognize which programming environment you are in or which programming language you are in, ... unable to help. Sorry.

Comment: @LukeSideWalker thanks for your comment, I just started using stackoverflow so apologies for not making the question clear. I have now added my code and a more extensive description of the problem.

Comment: Now, that you have posted your code, I can't see any "positioning"-code for your TableViewController. So I suppose, you set the position for your tableView in your storyboard, right? What do you want to achieve? Do you want to change the position of your TableView or do you want to change the order of your data shown in your tableView?

Comment: Yes, I set the position for the tableView in my storyboard. I would like the table view to be shown above the button. Currently, the issue is that my button opening the table view is positioned low on the screen, hence, when I open the table view not all of its content is visible. In the question above I also attached a screenshot showing this problem.

Comment: Well maybe you have to rethink your UI design a little bit. When there is not enough space for your TableView below your button, you could simply place your tableView ABOVE your button and make it hidden. Then set hidden to false (programmatically), when you want to present the TableView (and after that set hidden to true again).